# Access env variables inside docker entrypoint script

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint

I want to pass environment variables in my `docker run` command and access them in my entrypoint shell script.

This is my super simple `Dockerfile` for test purposes:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /

ADD entrypoint.sh .

RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

And this is the `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "env var TEST = ${TEST} "
```

I just build the `Dockerfile` like this: `docker build -t test:1.0 .`

And then run it like this: `docker run -i test:1.0 -e TEST='Hello world'`

Unfortunately the output is not containing the env var.

Comment: Docker options like `-e` need to come _before_ the image name.  Things after the image name are interpreted as the command to run.  If you `echo "$1"` inside the script you should see the `-e` option come back out.  (Should the script have a `exec "$@"` line to actually run that command?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record: Predefining the variables is not the solution.

The order of the args is important, like [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) said.

```sh
# incorrect
docker run -i test:1.0 -e TEST='Hello world'

# correct
docker run -i -e TEST='Hello world' test:1.0
```

Comment: David Maze is actually right - it's just the order of the args that make the env var work...

Answer (score -1):

Something like this will work:

**entrypoint.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $MYVAR
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.15.4
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
ENV MYVAR=""
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/home/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And then you can build & run the container while setting the environment variable with:

```
$ docker build -t test . && docker run -e MYVAR="hello world" test
```